# perl prove errors out with "Archive is not a known format type"

Tags: perl, perl-prove

When trying to run Perl prove , i am unable to run prove , and get the following error:

```
find test/ -name '*.t' ! -name '*falcon*' | xargs \

prove --norc -r test/ -formatter=TAP::Formatter::JUnit | tee test_results.xml
```

error:

```
Archive is not a known format type! at /usr/lib/perl5/5.8.8/App/Prove.pm line 538.
```

Versions used: TAP::Harness v3.28 and Perl v5.8.8, OS = CentOs 6.4

Answer (score 0):

I am guessing you are wishing to run all tests, except those containing falcon in the name.

There are issues with the command:

1) formatter option starts with a double hyphen '--'

2) the prove is being told to recurse into /test

This worked for me:

```
find test/ -name *.t | grep -v falcon | prove --norc --formatter \
   TAP::Formatter::JUnit | tee test_results.xml
```